# Cant Load Image on Java (BlueJ)

Tags: java, image, awt, bluej

Im Trying to load my images on to Java but when running the code nothing appears inside my JFrame.

The way im doing it is calling my Image function from my main:

```
    import java.awt.*;              // Graphics stuff from the AWT library, here: Image
    import java.io.File;            // File I/O functionality (for loading an image)
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;   // All images are used as "icons"



  public class GameImage
    {
  public static Image loadImage(String imagePathName) {

    // All images are loades as "icons"
    ImageIcon i = null;

    // Try to load the image
    File f = new File(imagePathName);


    if(f.exists()) {  // Success. Assign the image to the "icon"
        i = new ImageIcon(imagePathName);
    }
    else {           // Oops! Something is wrong.
        System.out.println("\nCould not find this image: "+imagePathName+"\nAre file       name and/or path to the file correct?");            
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // Done. Either return the image or "null"
    return i.getImage();

} // End of loadImages method

}
```

And then calling it here:

```
        GI_Background = GameImage.loadImage("Images//background.jpg");
    GI_DuskyDolphin = GameImage.loadImage("Images//DuskyDolphin.jpg");
```

If this is not enough information I'll gladly supply the rest of the code :)
Thanks

Comment: Show what you do with the images: how you attempt to display them. Since (presumably) the program doesn't exit this code is probably OK.

Comment: Ok so you have this image `GI_Background`, but what do you do with it? Do you add it to a label, do you paint it? I don't see you doing anything with it.

Comment: By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Answer (score 1):

*If the image is part of the application,* do not use a File but use the java resource mechanism.

```
    URL imageUrl = getClass().getResource("/Images/background.jpg");
    return new ImageIcon(imageURL).getImage();
```

The resource URL will return null when not found.
If the application is packed in a .jar, you can open that with 7zip/WinZip or so, and check the path. It must be case-sensitive, and using `/` (not backslash).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you try to achieve...
to load an image with a method, this will be enough:

```
private Image loadImage(String fileName){
    return (new ImageIcon(fileName)).getImage();
}
```

Afterwards, i would create a JLabel with the Image as background;

```
ImageIcon image = getImage( filename );    

JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel( image );
imageLabel.setSize( image.getIconHeight, image.getIconWidth );

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add( imageLabel );
```

Try this and feel free to aks again if i does not work for you, or thats not want you want :)